# How to remove quotes and brackets from a dict that has two keys to one value in a jinja template?

Tags: python, jinja2

I am using `Python 3.52` and I have 2 keys to a single value in a dict:

code:

```
for key, value in unused_reserved_instances.items():
    print("Key: ", key)
    print("Value: ", value)
```

output:

```
Key:  ('m3.large', 'us-west-2b')
Value:  1
Key:  ('m3.xlarge', 'us-west-2b')
Value:  1
```

jinja template:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center;
}
table#t01 {
    width: 30%;    
    background-color: #f1f1c1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table id="t01">
  <tr>
    <th>Instance Type</th>
    <th>Count</th> 
  </tr>
{% for key, value in unused_reserved_instances.items() %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{key}}</td>
    <td>{{value}}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Instead of this:

```
Instance Type               Count
('m3.large', 'us-west-2b')   1
('m3.xlarge', 'us-west-2b')  1
```

I want it to be something like one of the below examples (just without the quotes and brackets):

```
Instance Type          Count
m3.large, us-west-2b     1
m3.xlarge, us-west-2b    1
```

Or maybe like this:

```
Instance Type          Count
m3.large - us-west-2b    1
m3.xlarge - us-west-2b   1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the strings in the tuple like so:

```
{% for key, value in unused_reserved_instances.items() %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{key|join(' - ')}}</td>
    <td>{{value}}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i got an error `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got ':'`

Comment: @Berlin Modified. Can you try again?

Comment: just to understand, why is it fail when I try to print, but with jinja its works?

Comment: `for key, value in unused_reserved_instances.items():`

Comment: `print("Key: ", key|join(' - '))`

Comment: In python you would do: `print(' - '.join(key))`. Syntax is bit different.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over that tuple:

```
<td>{% for v in key %}{{v}}{%endfor%}</td>
```